# Volcar datos json de una hoja de cálculo de Google en un arreglo bidimensional

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, array, google-spreadsheets

Problemas más al tomar datos de un json cuando obtengo los datos con jquery- each quiero volcar estos datos a un arreglo bidimensional pero solo volca el último renglón siendo que lo reviso con console log y si muestra bien el dato pero ya en el arreglo solo muestra el último.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var datos = new Array;
  var bufer = new Array;
  var bufer2 = new Array;
  var spreadsheetID = "1lWXlhc4yl5vFXBpkqJWf1oysxmpMM2DKWp3pPTQ2DXc";
  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/1/public/values?alt=json";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var entry = data.feed.entry;
  $(entry).each(function(){
bufer.push(this.gsx$area.$t,this.gsx$sarea.$t,this.gsx$obligatorio.$t,this.gsx$nombre.$t,this.gsx$fuente.$t,this.gsx$autor.$t,this.gsx$tipo.$t,this.gsx$reseña.$t,this.gsx$vínculo.$t,this.gsx$duración.$t,this.gsx$imagen.$t);});
  console.log(bufer.length);
  console.log(datos);
  for(var i=0; i<bufer.length/11; i++)
  {
    bufer2.length = 0;   bufer2.push(bufer[i*11],bufer[(i*11)+1],bufer[(i*11)+2],bufer[(i*11)+3],bufer[(i*11)+4],bufer[(i*11)+5],bufer[(i*11)+6],bufer[(i*11)+7],bufer[(i*11)+8],bufer[(i*11)+9],bufer[(i*11)+10]);
    console.log(bufer2);// aqui si aprece bien el dato
    datos.push(bufer2); //no se por que no lo volca correctamente

  }
console.log(datos);//son 60 entradas y en todas solo muestra la ultima
  });

console.log("no parecen mis datos"+datos);// cuando salgo de la función $.getJSON(url, function(data) los datos no se guardan en la variable y eso que se trata de una variable global.
});
```

Comment: Lo que te está tronando tu código es esta línea `bufer2.length=0` es términos prácticos estás reseteando el tamaño de tu arreglo y este nunca crece, ¿Para qué quieres esta línea? En mejores casos has `data.push(bufer[i*11], bufer[(i*11)+1]...)` y te ahorra usar un arreglo de por medio

Answer (score 0):

Ya conseguí resolver el problema no me pareció muy adecuado pero funciona. lo que hice fue declarar en cada ciclo la variable bufer y de esta manera se agrega la informacion de manera correcta.

```
var datos = new Array;
var bufer = new Array;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.modal').modal();

  var spreadsheetID = "1lWXlhc4yl5vFXBpkqJWf1oysxmpMM2DKWp3pPTQ2DXc";
  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/1/public/values?alt=json";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var entry = data.feed.entry;

  $(entry).each(function(){
    bufer.push(this.gsx$area.$t,this.gsx$sarea.$t,this.gsx$obligatorio.$t,this.gsx$nombre.$t,this.gsx$fuente.$t,this.gsx$autor.$t,this.gsx$tipo.$t,this.gsx$reseña.$t,this.gsx$vínculo.$t,this.gsx$duración.$t,this.gsx$imagen.$t);
  });

  for(var i=0; i<bufer.length/11; i++)
  {
    var bufer2 = new Array;
    bufer2.push(bufer[i*11],bufer[(i*11)+1],bufer[(i*11)+2],bufer[(i*11)+3],bufer[(i*11)+4],bufer[(i*11)+5],bufer[(i*11)+6],bufer[(i*11)+7],bufer[(i*11)+8],bufer[(i*11)+9],bufer[(i*11)+10]);
    datos.push(bufer2);
  }

  });


});
```